# Merge arrays with strings and delete repetitive values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

From `WP_Query` I am dumping strings stored into separate arrays:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Portugal"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Spain"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Italy"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Monaco"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Spain"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Lithuania"
}
```

I am trying to merge those arrays into one array, delete repetitive strings like `"Spain"` and get the number of unique values.
I was trying to use `array_merge()`:

```
$tester = array();
    foreach($array_string as $value) {
                array_merge($tester, $value);
             }
          $result = array_unique($tester);
         print_r($result);
```

But without any decent results, error telling that `<b>Warning</b>:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array` Could someone tell where I am missing the point? Many thanks for all possible help, will be looking forward.

Comment: what is the type of $value

Comment: `array_merge` doesn't change in place the first parameter but returns the resulting array, so: `$tester = array_merge($tester, $value);`. However, using `array_map` is probably more elegant.

Comment: what is `$array_string` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted in the question is almost good. The intention is correct but you missed out a simple thing: you initialize `$tester` with an empty array and then never add something to it. In the end, it is still empty and [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) has nothing to do but return an empty array too.

The error is in the line:

```
array_merge($tester, $value);
```

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) does not change the arrays passed to it as argument. It returns a new array that your code ignores (instead of saving it into `$tester`).

This is how your code should look like:

```
$tester = array();
foreach($array_string as $value) {
    $tester = array_merge($tester, $value);
}
$result = array_unique($tester);
print_r($result);
```

---

#### Solution #2

You can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to invoke [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and pass the values of `$array_string` as arguments. The returned array contains duplicates; passing it to [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) removes them:

```
$result = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array_string));
```

#### Solution #3

A simpler (and possibly faster) way to accomplish the same thing is to use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the values into an array and then pass it to `array_unique()`, of course:

```
$result = array_unique(array_column($array_string, 0));
```

This solution works only with PHP 5.5 or newer (the `array_column()` function doesn't exist in older versions.)

Answer (score -1):

To get the number of unique strings in the merged array you will have to set empty array before `WP_Query`

```
$tester = array();
```

Than inside while loop of `WP_Query` every string is put into separate array and pushed to `$tester`

```
foreach((array)$array_string as $key=>$value[0]) {
           array_push($tester,$value);
               }
```

Unique values in array `$tester` is found using `array_unique()` functions that should be placed after `WP_Query` while loop.

```
$unique_array_string = array_unique($tester, SORT_REGULAR);

$unique_string_number =  sizeof($unique_array_string);
```

Answer (score -1):

You will create an array and will take key of the array for cities names  like spain..etc And it will give different cities name always...

```
     $data= array();    

    $data1 = array("Portugal");
    $data2 = array("Spain");
    $data3 = array("Italy");
    $data4 = array("Monaco");
    $data5 = array("Spain");
    $data6 = array("Lithuania");
    $merge = array_merge($data1, $data2,$data3,$data4,$data5,$data6);

    $data = array();

    foreach($merge as $value) {

        $data[$value] = $value;

    }
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';
```

Comment: Have you tried the code before posting it as an answer? [It doesn't work](https://3v4l.org/WbZQP).